# How to revert a dirty editor to the last saved contents?

Tags: visual-studio

Some other IDEs and text editors have a "revert" feature for dirty (unsaved) editors, whereby you can easily (in one step) throw away all unsaved changes in a file and revert back to the last saved contents. In Eclipse, for example, the feature is described as

> The Revert action is equivalent to closing an editor without saving, then reopening on the previously saved contents.

Is there any such feature in Visual Studio (2017)?